# Logging browser statistics (width) on my website

Tags: javascript, asp.net, viewport

As an attempt to study responsive web design, I am logging all browser activity on my website.  One parameter I wish to capture is the viewport width.  So when a client (user) visits the homepage, I use VB.NET to store the user parameters in a sql table.

I have used some code from a fellow contributor, however I do not understand the code fully.  Now, I don't really need to get the exact script to work.  What I would like is to get the screen width from the page after jscript event has fired.  Grab the value and store it in a SQL table.

A problem is that the value is not available in VB.NET code behind until the page is fully rendered.  One contributor has suggested a "click next to continue" button to capture the client variable.  I do not want to do this as it is not conducive to the design of the website.

You can test this web page here: https://happinessforlife.org/getBrowser

Existing script that is included in the page source code is as follows:

```
function SetWidthHeight() {
    var height = $(window).height();
    var width = $(window).width();
    context.Session["BrowserWidth"] = height;
    context.Session["BrowserHeight"] = width;
```

};

And then there is an ASHX file in the website root directory.  Code as follows:

```
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="windowSize" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

/// 

public class windowSize : IHttpHandler , System.Web.SessionState.IRequiresSessionState  {

public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {
    context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
    
    var json = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    var output = json.Serialize(new { isFirst = context.Session["BrowserWidth"] == null });
    context.Response.Write(output);
    
    context.Session["BrowserWidth"] =  context.Request.QueryString["Width"]; 
    context.Session["BrowserHeight"] = context.Request.QueryString["Height"];
}

public bool IsReusable
{
    get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
}
```

Thanks for Albert D Kallal for pointing me in the right direction.  I have simplified the script as follows:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="myLabelBrowserWidth" Visible="False"/>
<script>
    document.getElementById("myLabelBrowserWidth").innerHTML = 
window.innerWidth;
```

Then the value is got from myLabelBrowserWidth.text.  Only after a page click.

Comment: Well, you don't need a next to continue. What is the first page they land on? Any button they click WILL cause a post back. So, you can have that hidden field or label get set by the js code after page is sent to client. Now code behind with ease simply get/grab/use that hidden field value. I would do this at logon time, but if you don't have a logon then surely you must have some type of start or landing page for the site? Any post back from that landing page is a chance to get and save that information. So grab the value from the main landing page post back (on-load) event.

Comment: My landing page just does a lot of prep-work.  Once the prep-work is done, it transfer control to another page.  I was hoping to log the browser width in the start "page".  My website goes from Default.asp to Default2.aspx.

Comment: You don't have a lot of choice here. You CAN/could do a ajax call on that first page, and thus not have to wait for the user to hit a button or say wait for some post-back. So it is possible on the first landing page to have js do a ajax call (web method) to tuck away this information. But, it simply easier to capture the information on post-back. Given that you have to run that wee bit of js code to set the hidden controls with the several values (might as well capture what browser they are using too! - then at that point that code could just go ahead and do the ajax call to your web method.

Comment: so you can have this occur automatic. You on ready event has to run that js code anyway. So at the end of that js code stub, it could do the ajax (web method) call, and you would not have to get/grab/capture the hidden fields on post back. I just think that since a post back of some sort HAS to occur on that landing page, then it easier to get those values at that point in time. But in both cases, since you need that wee bit of js to run to set those width controls, then I suppose that SAME we bit of js can and could simply make that ajax (web method) call. This gets values without post-back

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  I will get back to you.